# How to have a Nat gateway for all ip's in AWS and allow returning traffic to not going through the NAT Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, nat

I want to use an external service black lists ip's if they detect too much traffic from them (anti DOS). Thus I need to to be able to give this service a specific ip so they can whitelist that ip.

So I create my nat gateway and set up the routing such any traffic going to this service goes via the nat gateway.

The problem is this service is also a cloud service so its ip address is not static.

So best case is that I can setup a filter for all IP addresses and route this via the nat gateway. Problem with this is the returning traffic also goes via the nat gateway. So this means I can no longer ssh into my instances or connect to my db from outside because as it's a secure link and requires the return to go via the same route.

According to what I see in Network ACL config I can treat returning traffic differently from sending traffic - this is via ports. But it doesn't seem like I can do the same with a nat gateway...

Is there a way to not send returning traffic through the nat gateway? Or another solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> So this means I can no longer ssh into my instances or connect to my db from outside

Is this the only issue, or is the external service establishing connections to your hosts (versus replying via a single connection that's initiated by your host)?

If the former, then there are two things that you can do. The first is to use a VPN, so that your computer or network is logically part of the VPC. The second, and imo far more prevalent for small sites, is to use a [bastion host](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/linux-bastion/): an EC2 instance that lives on a public subnet and allows SSH tunnels to your instances on the private subnet(s).

You could also expose the DB with a public IP, to avoid the need to tunnel, although I really don't recommend this. As long as your instances on the private subnet use the AWS-exposed endpoint (or a Route53 alias for that endpoint) they'll connect to the DB's private IP.